# Store user credentials in 3 tier architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services

For our product we are currently storing customer credentials hashed in db (3 tier architecture) . We want the authentication to be done at 1st tier itself ,which aws solution can be  used for this ,May be AWS HSM but what changes need to be done at app layer to do this .

1. This is a website
2. using cloudfront to route across across edge
3. using database replication

also we have active-active multi region .
any suggestions would be useful
thanks

Comment: Please, describe your architecture with more details. Note that AWS HSM does not store customer credentials but private or secret keys.

Comment: i dont want the customer request to go until database to validate the login .. the HSM can store the secret ?

Comment: You should better look at AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM). HSM is for storing encryption keys and computing cryptographic operations without the need to export those keys outside the HSM. Not the best way to store user credentials. Could be a place to generate user credentials (for instance, signing those credentials with a key stored in the HSM). But look at IAM. Seems better for your needs.

Comment: So you're looking to store you encryption key somewhere and not the actual passwords? What type of hashing are you using? You might want to look into KMS.

Comment: can kms store validate logins across regions

Answer (score 0):

I agree that some further details on your architecture would help. Is this a web application, mobile app, other fat client? How are you achieving the active-active multi-region architecture at the DB? I would like to suggest AWS Cognito but the multi-region needs become a bit more complex in that scenario.

Today how do you determine which region your users are routed to? If using AWS Cognito you'd likely need to create a user pool per region but this means your users would need to be routed to the correct user pool based on their region.

I have had great luck with AWS Cognito identities from web, mobile, and fat client apps and have even used many of the Lambda integrations with Cognito for commercial grade applications. Some good examples -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/walkthrough-using-the-ios-sdk.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-android-sdk.html

Comment: hi just added the info